# Reach hardware and user informations with monodroid?

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin

I need to reach informations about u device informations like android version or device/publisher id and some basic hardware informations.
 so how should i follow for reach that informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Android version, there is [`Android.OS.Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) class.

To get some basic hardware information, there is [`Android.OS.Build`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class. It contains a few hardware information string properties, like: `Build.CPU_ABI`, `Build.DEVICE`, `Build.DISPLAY`, `Build.MANUFACTURER`, `Build.MODEL` etc.

To get device id, it's a little bit tricky. It really depends. You may take a look at ["Identifying App Installations"](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) from Android Developer's blog. And answers to this question: ["Is there a unique Android device ID?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id/) might help as well.